# Custom segue from left to right for form sheets (iPad)

Tags: ios, ipad, segue

I have some view controllers in a form sheet and right now they all push segue. But I want to make an animation that makes them come from right to left during segue throughout the page. so when I go to the next view controller my segue should start bringing the view controller from the right and the parent view controller starts to move to the left and goes off the screen/fades and the child view controller comes from right and settles at the center of the iPad like how form sheets do. I was wondering if anyone had implemented something like that before? if not, can I get some suggestions in how to do this so that I can get a head start? I have just have a little experience with custom segues, where I could use QuartzCore to animate the view controllers and since they all belong to the same navigation controller I am not sure how can I achieve this fly from right to center and to left animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own full-sized view controller and emulate form sheet's behavior inside it by yourself (with gesture recognizers etc)